# What are the significant differences between $("#myElement") and $(myElement)?

Tags: jquery

I've noticed that almost everyone uses the standard CSS ID selector when acquiring an element instance with jQuery like `$("#myElement")`.  My preference is to just reference the element itself like `$(myElement)`.  I have noticed one difference between the two, and that's how referencing the element directly when it exists inside a form will result in the element not being found, whereas using the CSS ID selector will find the element every time.

Why should I use one over the other?

Comment: because `$(myElement)` will use a variable? So that one must exist

Comment: @devqon It would if CSS selector `#myElement` returns an element

Comment: There isn't on all HTML5 compliant browsers and if `window.myElement` property isn't overwritten. But don't use it!  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: Not sure about all the downvotes, seems legit question to me

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `$('#myElement')` is creating a jQuery object using the string selector passed in to it. In this case it will create an object from the DOM element which as the `id` of `myElement`.

On the other hand, `$(myElement)` will create a jQuery object from whatever value is stored in the `myElement` variable. It could be a string, eg `"#myElement"`, or it could be a native JS DOMElement. It could also be another jQuery object however this is pointless logic and should be avoided.

For more information see [jQuery() in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

Comment: Be aware about HTML5 refering element:  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 0):

Every one is for a particular case. When you do

```
$('#myElement')
```

jQuery is first trying to find an element with `id="myElement"` attribute.

And in this case:

```
$(myElement)
```

the code will only work if you have `myElement` variable containing `element object`. This line alone will **not** work.

Here's two equivalent operations:

```
// Find element manually
var el = document.getElementById('myElement');
var obj = $(el);

// Use jQuery power
var obj = $('#myElement');
```

You cannot replace one with another: each of them has its own mission.

Comment: Again, this has been standardized in HTML5 even it should be avoided in all cases: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object

Comment: window.myElement will exist if there is an HTML element with id or name="myElement"

Answer (score 0):

> how referencing the element directly when it exists inside a form will
>   result in the element not being found

you can check your element (by selector) exist like a

```
if($(variable|"string").length > 0) { 
   console.log('element exist and do something'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that $(myElement) will be the window.myElement that is cast to a jQuery object. I do NOT recommend you assume that $(myElement) will resolve.

All these 3 exist

```js
$(function() {
    window.console&&console.log(myElement); // DOM id="myDiv" or name="myElement" for elements that support name attribute
    window.console&&console.log($(myElement)); // DOM -> jQuery object
    window.console&&console.log($("#myElement")); // jQuery object
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myElement">My Element</div>
```